# Delay shared element transition to complete statelist animation

Tags: animation, android-5.0-lollipop, rippledrawable, shared-element-transition, activity-transition

I've been trying out shared element transition on Lollipop. i have a recyclerview which loads some cards and one click the card expands to its details in the next activity.

I have set a ripple effect and a StateListAnimator on the card. But those are not visible cause the transition starts before these effects are completed.

Is there any way to delay the transition so that it can wait for the statelist animator and ripple to complete?

Here is the code I use

```
ActivityOptions options = null;
        if (Utilities.isLollipop()) {
            options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, Pair.create(view, "hero_view"), Pair.create((View) fab, "fab"));
 startActivity(detailIntent, options.toBundle());
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really want to delay the activity transition like that? The user might think the delay is lag.

Comment: The idea was to show the touch interaction before moving into the transition, so that the user gets a feedback where he touched..

Comment: I don't think any of the standard Google apps (like Google Music, Newsstand, etc.) do anything like this. Have you compared how your app to the behavior in other apps like these? Just wondering.

Comment: You got a point there. And this exercise was not for an app. I was just playing around with the transitions. And I also agree that the effect is not a good idea... But i would wonder why Google introduced a StateListAnimator if you can never see what it does..

Comment: There are plenty of times when you see what a StateListAnimator does... maybe immediately before an activity starts just isn't one of those times. :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a work around, but I still would want to know what is the right way of doing this and therefore leaving the question open.

The work around I did was
1. remove the state list animator and add that as an animator in the onclick method.
2. Used a Handler to post a delayed call to the activity

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {

                          Intent i=new Intent(SearxhJobs.this,JobsTypes.class);
                          startActivity(i);
                      }
                  }, 200);
```

P.S- I did end up removing the effect as it was not very intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

The way that may help some that already have the Transitions setup in Second Activity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getWindow().getSharedElementEnterTransition().setDuration(500);
    getWindow().getSharedElementReturnTransition().setDuration(500)
        .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
}
```