# Delay enter transition animation until shared element placement

Tags: android, transition, shared-element-transition

I have an activity with a shared element that transitions into another activity. This works fine but the problem is the second activity has some dividers that get drawn on top of the previous activity which looks weird. I saw this video which shows that the enter transition can be delayed until the shared element is placed:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhiPJByIMrM&index=8&list=WL

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44565992/2599596