# Android RecyclerView - can't see ripple effect, because another Activity is started

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecycleView` with custom rows. The click on a row is handled via `RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener`.

My custom row has a ripple effect set:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:background="@drawable/list_item_bg"
```

Everything works as expected, i can see the ripple effect.
BUT... When I start a new `Activity` when a row is clicked, it launches immediately and the ripple effect is not visible anymore.

Is there a way, so that the new Activity runs only after the ripple animation?

**OnItemTouchListener.java**

```
public class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private RecyclerClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final RecyclerClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
    }
}
```

**@drawable-v21/list_item_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/green_dark">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/green"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</ripple>
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29224653/delay-shared-element-transition-to-complete-statelist-animation/44565992#44565992)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Handler` and add some delay before going to new Activity, so the `Ripple` animation can be seen

**Code**

```
 @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child)); //perform Task
                }
            }, 1000);  //dealy Time
        }
        return false;
    }
```

A much better and cleaner approach is to use `View.OnClickListener` instead of Touch. It will show the animation first automatically.

Here is Good [Example](http://tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/12/android-recyclerview-item-click-listener-ripple-effect.html)

Comment: Just tried the cleaner approach. I fire the OnClickListener from the ViewHolder, but it behaves the same. It doesn't wait for the ripple effect to finish.

Comment: Make sure to remove the `RecyclerTouchListener`.. reference from your recyclerview and use adapter to `setClickListener()`..

Comment: I did, removed the RecycleTouchListener from the RecyclerView and added the listener to the adapter. Works fine, just can't see the animation.

Comment: Ok, i must've messed up somewhere. Now it works.
Tried to use the same method for another RecyclerView, which hides, after clicking on a row. Same thing happens: RecyclerView is hidden before the animation finishes.

The example above helped me actually. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for your problem would be to delay the effect of action.

```
// onClick
yourView.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        yourContext.startActivity(new Intent(yourContext, YourActivity.class)
            /*.putExtra(...)*/);
    }
}, ANIMATION_DURATION_MILLIS);
```

Note: You may need to prevent multiple clicks using some boolean flags.